# How to pass a json object as a parameter to the webservice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsmutableurlrequest

I am using a webservice which takes json object as parameter. Here's my code:

```
    -(void)createHttpHeaderRequest {

        NSString *x = @"{\"GetVehicleInventory\": {\"ApplicationArea\": {\"Sender\": {\"ComponentID\":}}}" (something like that)

        NSString *sample = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://trialservice.checkitout?XML_INPUT=%@",x];
 NSString * final = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)sampleReq, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=\""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
 NSMutableRequest *request = [NSMutableREquest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:final]];
    NSURLConnection * theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        if (theConnection) {
            NSLog(@"Service hit");
        }
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        NSError * error;
        NSDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        NSArray * categories = [dict objectForKey:@"category"];
        [self.delegate giveControlBackToController:categories];

    }
```

When I am trying to NSLog sample it gives me the complete URL which on pasting into a browser gives me the result back, but when I am calling NSLog on the request, it shows null and nothing happens after this.
The control never goes to its NSURLConnection delegate method.

Comment: Please make the effort to use correct English and paste some code that at least compiles.

Comment: You're creating an NSMutableRequest called `request` but then initializing your NSURLConnection with something called `theRequest`.  Does that reflect your actual code or is that just an error introduced when you copied it here?

Comment: That's just an error which got introduced here. Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you implemented `connection: didReceiveResponse:` in your delegate?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that most browsers automatically escape URLs whilst NSURL doesn't. You'll need to do it manually; have a look at the [CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cfurlcreatestringbyaddingpercentescapes&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CF0QFjAB&url=http://www.bagonca.com/blog/2009/04/08/iphone-tip-1-url-encoding-in-objective-c/&ei=qUAQULfPKsz1sgaA0YHoCA&usg=AFQjCNH7KgY378BfxzANF1AXlZn7Tkn6uA) function.

Comment: OK. So i tried this and it's not giving me null now but still doesn't hit the delegate method plus the the url is now filled with a lot of %7D etc. Any other suggestions??

Comment: Have you set the delegate? Have you even created an NSURLConnection?

Comment: Yes. NSURLConnection * theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

Comment: please see the edit above. Can't show the correct url or the json parameter but this is it.

Comment: @Ashutosh so have you finally added the percent escapes using the function I suggested? I don't see it anywhere. Also, in `connection:didReceiveData:` doesn't do what you think it does -- the data parameter is partial data and should be collected using an NSMutableData instance.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was in my code somehow it got skipped while pasting code here. And the connectionDidReceiveData is not even being called. I just want to hit the service and see the response. I have put a break point in the start of this delegate method just to see if the program reaches here.

Comment: Escape the JSON only, not the whole URL string.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment instead of an answer, but unfortunately you can't format code in a comment.  Add the following method to your delegate and see whether it gets called.  If it does, let us know what the response is.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSLog(@"Connection response code: %d", httpResponse.statusCode);
}
```

Comment: Its not getting called. But method didFailWithError does and it says NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “209.112.58.126” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0x6877b40 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “209.112.58.126” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x6c59390>}

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with the server configuration, then.  You say it works in a browser, though?